# How does heuristic work with multiple agents?

Tags: heuristics, multi-agent-systems, a-star

I have a question for heuristic search with multiple agents. I know how heuristic search works with one agent (ex. one Pacman) but I don't really understand it with multiple agents. Let's say we have this problem where Worm A has to get to its goal state A and Worm B to B, knowing that the agents can move only in vertical and horizontal way:
[image: Worm A should get to its goal state A and Worm B to its goal state B]

If we had only Worm B, the optimal cost from starting position to the goal position would be `9`, since one action costs `1` and it'd follow the path `RIGHT-RIGHT-RIGHT-RIGHT-RIGHT-RIGHT-UP-UP-UP`.

My question is, if we have two worms, like in the picture, the optimal cost would be `9 + optimal cost for Worm A`?

Also, strictly for this problem with 2 agents, if we use Manhattan distance as a heuristic for **one agent**, would it be admissible if we take the **average of Worm A and B heuristics** for a problem with **two agents**?

Another question, I know for a fact that **sum of two admissible heuristics** won't be admissible for one agent but would it be for the problem with **two agents**?

These two worms are dependent of each other. How? If one worm moves from position X to Y, the position X is marked as a wall and is not an available field to move in. So if one worm has been in a specific position, that position is no more free for moving in.

For example, if we have something like `B^^^X^^^`, where B is the Worm B, `^` is an **available** **field** and `X` is a **wall**, after one RIGHT action it'll look like `XB^^X^^`, after one more RIGHT: `XXB^X^^` etc.

Comment: Your questions are interesting, but, please, **ask one question per post*, even though they are somehow related. If you have $N$ questions, create $N$ posts. So, please, try to simplify this post and ask only one question.

Comment: @nbro Thank you for reaching this and commenting. I didn't want to look like a spam, that's why I asked these questions in one post. How ever, I'll have this in mind for asking questions in the future :)

Comment: Please, try to simplify this question is a little bit more. I couldn't even read it until the end because it contains too much information for my brain to process :)